# How to integrate Azure text to speech with streamlit?

Tags: python

I am trying to integrate azure text to speech with streamlit.

```
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
import streamlit as st

st.title("Let's learn Math!")

def recognize_from_microphone():
    speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription="743ae1f5555f49f9a5de4457d4e91b2d", region="australiaeast")
    speech_config.speech_recognition_language="en-US"

    #To recognize speech from an audio file, use `filename` instead of `use_default_microphone`:
    #audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(filename="YourAudioFile.wav")
    audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(use_default_microphone=True)
    speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)

    st.text("Speak into your microphone.")
    speech_recognition_result = speech_recognizer.recognize_once_async().get()

    if speech_recognition_result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
        st.text("Recognized: {}".format(speech_recognition_result.text))
    elif speech_recognition_result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.NoMatch:
        st.text("No speech could be recognized: {}".format(speech_recognition_result.no_match_details))
    elif speech_recognition_result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.Canceled:
        cancellation_details = speech_recognition_result.cancellation_details
        st.text("Speech Recognition canceled: {}".format(cancellation_details.reason))
        if cancellation_details.reason == speechsdk.CancellationReason.Error:
            st.text("Error details: {}".format(cancellation_details.error_details))
            st.text("Did you set the speech resource key and region values?")

text = st.text_input("Enter text", value="Hi", max_chars=5)

def audio_output(text):

    speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription="743ae1f5555f49f9a5de4457d4e91b2d", region="australiaeast")
    audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioOutputConfig(use_default_speaker=True)

    # The language of the voice that speaks.
    speech_config.speech_synthesis_voice_name='en-US-JennyNeural'

    speech_synthesizer = speechsdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)

    # Get text from the console and synthesize to the default speaker.
    st.write("Enter some text that you want to speak >")

    speech_synthesis_result = speech_synthesizer.speak_text_async(text).get()

    if speech_synthesis_result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted:
        st.write("Speech synthesized for text [{}]".format(text))
    elif speech_synthesis_result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.Canceled:
        cancellation_details = speech_synthesis_result.cancellation_details
        st.write("Speech synthesis canceled: {}".format(cancellation_details.reason))
        if cancellation_details.reason == speechsdk.CancellationReason.Error:
            if cancellation_details.error_details:
                st.write("Error details: {}".format(cancellation_details.error_details))
                st.write("Did you set the speech resource key and region values?")

    recognize_from_microphone()
    audio_output(text)
```

This is my code, but streamlit is not loading the functions at all. Is there any fix? I am new to streamlit and azure.

Answer (score 0):

You declared the functions but didn't called them.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).